# How to set forms.RadioSelect() as a required field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a simple model:

```
class Books(models.Model):
   on_loan = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False)
```

And a simple form:

```
class BooksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'on_loan': forms.RadioSelect(choices=[
            (True, 'Book is on loan.'),
            (False, 'Book is not on loan'), ],
            )
        }
```

This form renders fine, with two radio inputs for true/false. However, when I submit the form it still validates as passing. Surely it should fail as the field is required and blank/null?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> How to set forms.RadioSelect() as a required field

Try add `attrs={"required": True}` for RadioSelect

```
widgets = {
    'on_loan': forms.RadioSelect(
        choices=[
            (True, 'Book is on loan.'),
            (False, 'Book is not on loan'), 
        ],
        attrs={"required": True}
    )
}
```